# Restrição de acesso à dados de usuário autenticado - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, autenticação, laravel-5.3

Eu tenho uma tabela que se relaciona com outra e essa se relaciona com algum usuário. Como faço para que apenas o dono dessa relação possa alterar/excluir o item. Mesmo que eu apenas traga no formulário os registros que tem relação, se por acaso eu alterar o identificador que estou passando vou poder alterar, então, gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de realizar essa verificação internamente de alguma forma genérica pois tenho diversos casos assim.

Comment: Fiz uma resposta, porém sua pergunta está vaga, poderia elaborá-la melhor e se possível postar o trecho do seu código para que eu reformule a resposta?

Comment: Tenho qual usuário está logado, mas como faço a verificação de uma forma genérica durante uma edição, por exemplo.

Comment: ..durante uma edição para saber se ele está realmente relacionado com o usuário logado..

Comment: Você pode armazenar o user_id na tabela que quer comparar, e fazer `Auth::user()->id == $objeto->user_id`, é possível até criar um middleware para isso

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo de como eu poderia fazer esse middleware? Não estou conseguindo criar uma lógica que me permita fazer isso de modo genérico

Comment: Como o middleware `Auth`, você coloca as rotas que passarão por ele dentro de um `group` com esse `middleware` e dentro dele vc faz as verificações. É uma alternativa para que você não crie várias vezes a mesma validação.. Dê uma olhada na documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível acessar o usuário autenticado na parte do server.

```
Auth::user()->oAtributoQueDeseja
```

ou atribua ele a um usuário temporário:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

---

Lembrando que você precisa importar essa `Facade`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```